# Any English learning resources similar to Pimsleur, but suitable for intermediate to advanced speakers?

Tags: resource-request, english

I like Pimsleur because it teaches you to speak in the context of full sentences and dialogs rather than isolated grammar rules and vocabulary lists. Are there any similar resources for learning more advanced speaking? I have already tried Fluentu, but the dialogs are too artificial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wanna try the Assimil or the Cortina language series. The way that they work is they present a dialogue for you to learn, on one side in the target language, and on the other your native language. That way you can digest entire sentences, paragraphs, dialogues, etc. instead of hammering straight vocabulary and grammar. At least in the Cortina books there is a vocab section containing the words used in the dialogue before the start of each dialogue, and at the bottom of each page is a footnote section explaining the grammar rules used in the dialogue. Assimil is pretty similar to my understanding.

You can download the Cortina books/MP3s for free here: https://fsi-languages.yojik.eu/languages/cortina.html

The Cortina books are also available for really cheap on Amazon.

Assimil is also available on Amazon, but it's a bit pricier. It's usually considered the superior resource (for European languages at least) so there's that to keep in mind as well. Sometimes you can catch good sales on this series at Schoenhof's Foreign Books' website.